# Log UIControl events

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there a way of logging the UIControl events that are going on when you touch the screen on the iPhone?

Here's an example - I need to show some information when the user touches down on a button but then lifts their finger outside. However this bit of code doesn't seem to work:

```
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(showInfo) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown & UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(showInfo) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
 [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(showInfo) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

Do it like this.

On topic:

You could inherit the UIButton class and override the following methods:

> Responding to Touch Events
>
> – touchesBegan:withEvent:
>
> – touchesMoved:withEvent:
>
> – touchesEnded:withEvent:
>
> – touchesCancelled:withEvent:

Comment: Re answer - that combination was too loose and got triggered on Touch Down. There're probably other combinations but this one worked for me: UIControlEventTouchDragOutside|UIControlEventTouchUpOutside. However, thanks for the OT response - if you want to update your answer I'll tick it off.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(showInfo:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragOutside|UIControlEventTouchUpOutside|UIControlEventTouchDragInside|UIControlEventTouchDown];
```